Convert Database Text field into Date error
I use the following formula: CASE WHEN JobCompletedDate IS null THEN null
ELSE PARSE_DATE("yyyy-MM-dd", JobCompletedDate)
END
The date shows like this '2024-04-25' and have several null rows.
I received the following error message:
'I use the following formula: CASE WHEN JobCompletedDate IS null THEN null
ELSE PARSE_DATE("yyyy-mm-dd", JobCompletedDate)
END'
how can I solve this?
Thank you.
I want to convert the text field into date

where is the error message?

in Datastudio. I am using a database from BigQuery. Checked the database and the format of the field I am using is date, but Studios don't recognise it

Can you please edit the question and paste the error message.? it is not there in the question at the moment.

Like Hijesh posted, the error message is currently just a repeat of your first paragraph. Also, consider using back-ticks to delimit your formula and triple-back-ticks to delimit your error-message.
